# How to alter functionality of login controller in Laravel to pass a variable

Tags: laravel, variables, authentication, controller

I'm trying to set up my Laravel installation so that upon login it will populate the home page with information from my database. How can I compact a variable to send it to the home page?

I've tried declaring a variable like this in the login controller:

```
$post = Post::all();
```

But when i do that i get the following error:

> syntax error, unexpected '$post' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function
>   (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)

Also how can i compact a variable to send to the home page? The only code that directs the user to the home page is this line: `protected $redirectTo = '/home';`
and I can't compact a variable in that line because compact requires parentheses like this: `return view('/home', compact('post'));`

What I'm trying to accomplish is to get the home page to display the users posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Post;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::all();

        return view('home', compact('posts'));
    }
}
```

**Explanation**

To accomplish your goal, you don't have to change the `$redirectTo` property of the `LoginController.` Because it's the URL that needs to redirect, it needs to stay the same because still, you need to redirect to the home page.

All you have to do is alter `HomeController` which Laravel has already defined for you. The `index()` method is the one that's taking care of how to show the `home` page. So as the answer says alter that function.

Answer (score 0):

As after successful login you are redirected to home page, try to display the posts in `HomeController@index` and you do not need to make any modification to your login controller.

In your `HomeController` just import the Post model and return the posts to `index.blade.php` and display there, your HomeController will look like

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post; // path to your Post model
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::all();
        return view('home', compact('posts'));
    }
}
```

and in your `index.blade.php`, you can loop through your posts.